# Sql connecting 2 tables and getting data from column

Tags: sql, wordpress

Hello trying to get information and connect it and then display it as drop down list. 
I am not sure how to query it the right way to get all information i need.
So the table i am trying to get info is made of 4 columns . 
[mgm_member_options is the field i need to check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDMTz.jpgmgm_member_options)

and then there is meta_value column where all the data is saved. and i need to get from there id first_name , last_name and membership_type . and the reason why i need membership type is so i could filter the information cause i need one type of membership to be shown .

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_usermeta m
INNER JOIN wp_users s
    ON m.user_id = s.id AND
       m.meta_key = 'mgm_member_options' AND 
       meta_value LIKE '%coaches%'
```

[that the meta_value inforamtion is listed in there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASKbq.jpg)

---

1. umeta_id  user_id      meta_value          meta_key
2. 2313            7     mgm_member_options   data is in picture
3. 4352            7     first_name              Petras

---

List item

So when i run first query to find meta_key information that contains coaches it shows me result also includes user_id . gona show and example of result

1. umeta_id user_id      meta_key            meta_value

   310        4     mgm_member_options  doesnt fit to screen

   ```
   467       7     mgm_member_options  doest not fir here .
   ```

   And got no clue how  to to make it show users first name when it gets that result .

Comment: Can you please post the sample data of both the tables as text? rather than image?

Comment: Hello yes. so meta_key that all values are stored named "mgm_member_options"

Comment: I was asking about the tables data in tabular format not in array format.

Comment: but thats where all information is saved in that column called meta_value it contains all the other information other fields contains.